# python: increase loop while iterating

Tags: python, loops

The following code iterates through the whole matrix filled in with increasing numbers and checks the difference between every element in one row and elements in the same location of the previous row. For every iteration, if this difference of two elements is less than 3, the counter increases and then the loop breaks and continues to the next row. What I would like to do is trying to increase this loop every time there is a counter increase.
In other words, if for instance the loop runs into this condition after checking the first two rows and each row is length 3, the following iterations should be done considering row length = 6, and if this condition is met again later, then the considered row length should be 9 and so on.
To be clear, this code returns 3 but according to what I am trying to do, it should return 1.
I am not sure if this would be possible in python, but I will gladly consider suggestions.

I am sorry for not being clear but this is a bit hard to explain correctly, I will still try my best and feel free to ask me any specific questions that you may have, I'll be happy to answer. In this example, the loop subtracts the second row [4,6,6] from the first one [1,2,4] and since 4-1=3, 6-2=4 and 6-4=2, only the latter is less than 3 therefore k increases by 1. Then in the third with the second row, 7-6=1 which is < 3 therefore 8-6 does not need to be checked, and here too, k increases by 1, so now we have k=2, and in the last row, [9,9,10]-[7,7,8] gives us elements less than 3 therefore our k=3.
Now, what I am trying to do is the following:
once [4,6,6]-[1,2,4] increases k by 1, I would like the 1st and 2nd row to be treated as one sublist [1,2,4,4,6,6], therefore even the 3rd and 4th row will be one sublist [7,7,8,9,9,10] to subtract [1,2,4,4,6,6] from, which would not increase k as there are no elements whose difference is less than 3. If let's say this example had additional rows, then for each k increase, the matrix should be 'reshaped' every time by enlarging the sublist length of 3 additional elements.

I hope I am explaining this clearly enough. If not, feel free to ask.

```
 matrix=[[1,2,4],
    [4,6,6],
    [7,7,8],
   [9,9,10]]
cell_list=[]
for row in matrix:
    for cell in row:
        cell_list.append(cell)

len_cell_list=(len(cell_list))
len_matrix_row=len(matrix[0])
k=0
k_list=[]
for i in range(1,len(matrix)):
    for j in range(len_matrix_row):
        if abs(matrix[i][j]-matrix[i-1][j])<3:
            k+=1
            k_list.append(k)
            break
        continue
print(k_list[-1])
```

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're trying to do. `the following iterations should be done considering row length = 6` from the example all rows look to have length of 3? Are you just looking for the increased difference between values in two rows? I'm not sure how it's expecting to be an output of 1. So will need more explanation as to how or why 1 is expected. As if you increase the `3` on the comparison line by 3 each time the condition is met it'll still return 3.

Comment: I added an additional paragraph, I hope is clear, or else you can ask me.

Comment: So are the number of rows combined determined by what k is?

Comment: yes, pretty much. For this example the sublists length = 3, but as soon as k=1, then the sublists contain 6 numbers, if k=2 then the sublists contain 9 elements and so on.

Comment: .Then what if the first two lists don't meet the conditions for collapse what happens to the first list? Is it deleted? or left alone? what if there is a list with three variables between two lists with 6 variables, what happens? It's not impossible to do what you want but it won't be replaceable outside of this specific example.

Comment: in this task all the sublists are supposed to be the same size to begin with. if the first rows don't meet the condition then they should be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want.

```
import numpy
matrix=[[1,2,4],
    [4,6,6],
    [7,7,8],
[9,9,10]]

k = 0
end_of_matrix = False
changing_matrix = matrix[:]
while not end_of_matrix:
    end_current_loop = False
    for i in range(1, len(changing_matrix)):
        for j in range(len(changing_matrix[i])):
            if abs(changing_matrix[i][j] - changing_matrix[i-1][j]) < 3:
                k += 1
                end_current_loop = True
                break
        if end_current_loop:
            break
    if not end_current_loop:
        end_of_matrix = True
    else:
        changing_matrix = []
        for i in range(0, len(matrix), k+1):
            changing_matrix.append(list(numpy.concatenate(matrix[i:i+k+1])))
print(changing_matrix)
print(k)
```

Output:

```
[[1, 2, 4, 4, 6, 6], [7, 7, 8, 9, 9, 10]]
1
```